# Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///)

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, perl

Всем привет. Есть код берет данные из базы, и в соответствии с регуляркой записывает или не записывает данные в базе.
Код отдельно отрабатывается корректно, но если перед ним выполняется точно такой же sub, с подобной регуляркой, выдает ошибку. Я не могу понять от чего она возникает, из базы данные выдаются без проблем. данные в виде текста содержат данные вида '2400000032632'

```
sub CheckCorrectEanForSelfMake {
    my $sqlqueryean = "SELECT EAN FROM `eanfromreport` WHERE DESCRIPTION is NULL OR DESCRIPTION in ('NULL','NothingFind','') AND EAN is not NULL";
    my $dbquery1 = $db->prepare($sqlqueryean);
    $dbquery1->execute;
    my @rowPRODGRPs;#Задаем имя массиву
    while (my ($rowPRODGRP) = $dbquery1->fetchrow_array()) {
        push @rowPRODGRPs, $rowPRODGRP;
        my $EanNameFromDatabase = $rowPRODGRPs[$i];
        if ($EanNameFromDatabase =~ /^28/) {
            my $dbqueryifEanisStartWiht28 = "update EANFROMREPORT set DESCRIPTION = 'Own PRD' WHERE EAN = '$EanNameFromDatabase'";
            my $dbqueryEanisStartWiht28 = $db->prepare($dbqueryifEanisStartWiht28);
            $dbqueryEanisStartWiht28->execute;
            print "Thith is Own prd\n ";
        }
        else
        {
print "Not Own prd\n ";
        }
        $i++
    }
       return 1;
}
```

Выдает ошибку в строке `if ($EanNameFromDatabase =~ /^28/)`

```
Use of uninitialized value $EanNameFromDatabase in substitution (s///)
```

Comment: А вы смотрели чему равно значение `$EanNameFromDatabase` перед этим `if`-ом?

Comment: И действительно ли ошибка в этой строке? Ведь `=~ /^28/` - это поиск в строке по рег. выражения, а не замена (`m//`, а не `s///`).

Comment: то что вы пытаетесь сделать выполняется одним запросом. `update EANFROMREPORT set DESCRIPTION = 'Own PRD' WHERE EAN like '28%' and  (DESCRIPTION is NULL OR DESCRIPTION in ('NULL','NothingFind',''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут:

```
push @rowPRODGRPs, $rowPRODGRP;
my $EanNameFromDatabase = $rowPRODGRPs[$i];
```

Что такое `$i` и почему вы уверены, что значение этой переменной не больше значения последнего индекса в массиве `$rowPRODGRPs` (если вообще оно определено)?

Учитесь отлаживать программу. Если обычный отладчик слишком сложен для понимания, хотя бы с помощью модуля [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) и обычных `print`/`printf`:

```
use DDP;
# ...
    push @rowPRODGRPs, $rowPRODGRP;
    p @rowPRODGRPs; # выводим текущее состояние массива
    # значение переменной $i - именно так, не как %d:
    printf "i: '%s', \@rowPRODGRPs length: %d\n", $i, scalar @rowPRODGRPs;
# ...
```

И **никогда** **ничего** не пишите ничего без этих строк после шебанга:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# ну или use Modern::Perl;
```

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что не определил $i внутри sub. Спасибо.